# Typescript create a class hide other class and return a generic result

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am still getting my head around the generic classes, and I need to create other class dynamically. But I am not sure how to do it.

```
Class A {}

Class B<T> {
Return T
}

Const c = B(A); // which is T
```

Give abit more context on what I am trying to do.

I use angular and typescript 3.45. Create a form dynamically by resolve the right component. In the directive, I should be able to retrieve a generic class. And use it, without any knowledge about the class that it is creating. Follow the separation of concerns.

**UPDATE**

Finally I got part of the Generic type, but still a few grey areas where I am still struggling and unsure where to start. For anyone who is interested and maybe a bit confused, I hope this will help to give you a bit of clarification.

Take any input type and receive the same type. Code example, lets we call this generic type `U`.

```
function func(a: U): U {
  return a;
}
const c = func(arg: U); // after this line, c has a value of type U

// Same as 

const c = func(10); // now c = 10;
```

What I intend to ask is, for any input type and I get a generic type as return type. That is a silly, because the compiler infers type from the input and replace U with the actual custom or primitive type.

For my return generic type, maybe we can achieve it thru conditional type but I am still getting use to the whole type, casting type and hide type behind extends and implementations. [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Thanks for the answer, it is right answer for my current question.

Comment: What exaclty is your usecase?

Comment: you want `c` to be of type `T`?  What's `T`?  Or do you want `T` to be of type `A`?  In which case `B` is really just a function (not a class constructor)?  Maybe you can flesh out this code to constitute a true [mcve] along with a clear explanation of what you're trying to do as described in the [guidelines for asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Good luck!

Comment: @jonas I tried to create one of those dynamic react form with angular and typescript 3.45. I am using a directive to resolve a component, but without having to explicitly declaring it.

Comment: component: componentRef<T> = ref.resolvefactory(SpecialComponent); that causes an error SpecialComponent is not equal to T

Comment: `ComponentRef<SpecialComponent>` is the correct type. Or just omit the type as `const component = ref.resolveFactory(...)` and let typescript infer it

Comment: But I have a class variable that ha no type, will this be a problem from typescript practice?

Comment: @jcalz sorry for this confusing classes. I know my syntax is incorrect, but just trying to capture the main idea. I read typescript doc and tried examples I found. Also tried many tricks and styles, but unable to avoid having to explicit declare the class.

Comment: The best way to communicate what you need is with a [mcve] where the only issue present is the one you are having trouble with.  Improper syntax only makes things more confusing, and text like "I should be able to retrieve a generic class and use it without any knowledge about the class that is creating" is a bit too ambiguous for me to suggest anything.  @ORBIT's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56946700/2887218) seems like the correct one given what you've said here; if it does not suffice, we need actual code that shows your problem.  Good luck.

Comment: To answer the question of creating classes, you can just write, `return class Foo {}` it's valid javascript to create and return a class.

Comment: It is validate to do that, but that is not  what i want to do. [React Form](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-dynamic-components-forms), that is what I am trying to learn, and I have trouble assigning `component = componentRef(T)`. I don't want my form directive to know anything about which component I am using and inputs. Hiding those implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to instantiate a generic type in TypeScript

source **Rico Suter's** blog.
      [link](https://blog.rsuter.com/how-to-instantiate-a-generic-type-in-typescript/)

> But how would you write such a method in `TypeScript`? The main
>   problem is, that the generic type argument T is not available at
>   runtime because `TypeScript generics` are only used at compile time
>   for type checking and removed in the transpiled `JavaScript` code.

```
public class YourFactory
{
    public T Create<T>()
        where T: new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}

var yourFactory = new YourFactory();
var person = yourFactory.Create<PersonModal>();
```

refer [this](https://blog.rsuter.com/how-to-instantiate-a-generic-type-in-typescript/)